Problem with the convergence region of the series

Can the region of convergence of a functional series defined on the real axis consist of a half-interval and a segment?

Yes maybe! I understood this intuitively, but I couldn’t show it clearly. I decided to work with logarithms. Consider the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\left ( x-\frac{1}{2} \right )^n$$
The convergence region of this series will be $-1/2<x<3/2$. Now I want to add a segment, I decided to do it like this. Consider the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\left ( (x-2)^n+(x+1)^n \right )$$
It turns out that the area of ​​convergence will be $x\in (1,2]\cup (-2,-1]$
It seems to me that I started adding the segment incorrectly, and I also chose the wrong function to consider. Intuitively, I understand this question, but I can’t give a specific example...

I think you meant the intersection, which would be empty.

The area of convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\left ( (x-2)^n+(x+1)^n \right )$ is not $(1,2] \cup (-2,-1]$...

By the way, I am not sure to understand the question. For any region $D \subset \mathbb{R}$, define $$f : x \mapsto \left\lbrace \begin{array}{cc} 1 & \text{if } x \notin D \ 0 & \text{if } x \in D \end{array}\right.$$ Then the region of convergence of $x \mapsto \displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 0} f(x)$ is exactly $D$ (but this example is not very interesting, so what are you looking for ?)...

I just need such an example, something simpler

I just don't understand why this fits. Is D a half-interval and a segment?

Consider the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{x^n}{n}}$. This series has a convergence circle radius of $1$. Moreover, on the boundary the series converges everywhere except for one single point $x=1$ (diverges). Consequently, the real section of the convergence region is the half-interval $[-1,1)$. Now consider another series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{x^n}{n^2}}$. This series converges on the entire closure of the circle $|x|\leq 1$. This means that the real convergence section is the segment $[-1,1]$
@TheSilverDoe's example in the comments is very good, but misses an important point (not a mistake!): if we are talking about function series, then my example will be more natural than his, since power series are still real and one of them is an elementary function (second field logarithm)
